# "Review completed": why isn't the fate of that post decided?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, vote-to-close, low-quality-posts

I am talking about https://askubuntu.com/questions/338436/i-cannot-get-vpn-to-prompt-me-for-userid-and-password-when-the-always-ask-opti

At the same time the review screen shows
[image]

while the question looks like
[image]

My point is: when the votes remain valid for some time, why does the review system say "completed".

Link to the review: https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/152215

And for Braiam
[image]

Comment: Can I have a link to the review?

Comment: @Seth see above :)

Comment: This is not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

After lots of reviews, I found out why: https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/152094

Immediately someone through "Looks Good" the review process ends.

[image]

I couldn't find a metapost to support this.

Comment: He's asking why the review says "completed" when one more vote is needed.

Comment: That's not what it is saying however, see http://i.imgur.com/Hawx7rG.png What it is saying is, this review is  *over* and cannot be reviewed anymore.

Comment: @Braiam not correct, see the screenshot in my question.

Comment: @guntbert I'm never wrong! Just that I don't have the answer at the moment :P

Comment: @Braiam unsuccessful again, sorry, the question in question still exists.

Comment: @Braiam do you **know** this or **guess** - mind you the tag I used was "bug" and not "discussion".

Comment: @guntbert see my update, this is a guess, but seems just right.

Comment: You are convincing me that I was looking at the juncture of two review queues: The "low quality" queue - which I showed in my question and which was completed with the first "Looks Good" vote and the "close" queue which resulted in closing the question as "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: @guntbert no, the times don't match for that conclusion. My hunch is, that a single "Looks good" remove the post from the LQ queue. I scrapped the entire MSO for answers, but couldn't find anything that confirms my hunch about this behavior. You should create a meta-post in Meta Stackoverflow with the support tag asking to explain this behavior.

Comment: @guntbert ok, seems that this answer is in the right track http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161482/213575 the interesting part is: *I think that is fairly obvious that it is the same as saying it *"looks good", after all If you have fixed everything wrong with the post, then why would you still consider it low quality?*